# Can't generate a timestamp with javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, unix-timestamp

When I output the following code to console:

```
console.log(new Date().getTime());
```

It says this:

```
1382888243791
```

When I convert that code using an online converter like this http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm I get this:

```
Sun, 25 Dec 45791 23:16:31 GMT
```

Obviously... there is a problem here.  **The biggest problem being the year of 45791!**

How can I properly generate a date in javascript?

Comment: JS timestamps are in ms not in s. It's not like this is not defined...

Comment: It's not exactly obvious...  It just says "getTime()"  How was I supposed to know it was in milliseconds and not seconds?

Comment: Idunno. Maybe by looking it up? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FgetTime

Comment: Clearly, the function should read `getTimeInMs` which would make it more obvious.  Standard unix time stamps are in epoch time ie **seconds** since epoch.

Comment: Clearly the method is not called `getTimeInSecondsSinceTheUnixEpoch`

Comment: Haha, no, it's just generic - it says `getTime()` which leaves it open to interpretation.  I agree I should have checked the documentation but...  I would prefer it be more obvious (just another opinion, I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter you're using must work in seconds since The Epoch (Jan 1st, 1970 at midnight GMT). JavaScript works in *milli*seconds since The Epoch, so divide by 1000.

Comment: Thanks.  To expand upon your answer, this is the code I ended up with `Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)`.